# Запятая перед "и" при перечислении действий

Tags: пунктуация, перечисление

При перечислении трёх или более сущностей, запятая перед союзом "и", отделяющим последнюю сущность, в русском языке не ставится:

> Маша, Петя и Вася пошли гулять.

Но что насчёт подобных предложений:

> Позвони Васе, попроси его поговорить с Петей, и потом позвони мне.

Нужна ли здесь запятая перед "и потом"?

Comment: Что значит «сущности»? Сущность — это внутреннее содержание, внутренняя основа чего-то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом примере однородные подлежащие, во втором — однородные сказуемые. Правила одинаковые: запятая перед «и» не ставится.